# Example gradle script to build(clean, build) several projects in the right order

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

There are several projects that need to build in order. By build in order the meaning:

```
1. clean, build - project 2
2. clean, build - project 1
3. clean, build - project 4
4. clean, build - project 3
```

of each project.

```
-Root Folder
------- project1
-----------build.gradle
------- project2
-----------build.gradle
------- project3
-----------build.gradle
------- project4
-----------build.gradle
--build.gradle
--settings.gradle
```

build.gradle projects (1,2,3,4):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
// other dependencies
}
```

root_folder/settings.gradle

```
include ':project1', ':project2', ':project3', ':project4'
```

root_folder/build.gradle

```
????????
```

Please tell me how to organize the build order of all the projects in a script?

Comment: Why is the order of execution important? Is it because `project1` /depends/ on `project2`? In that case, you should organize their /dependencies/ properly, and gradle will take care of the execution order automatically. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html Edit: I don't understand your use of the word "collect", please clarify.

Comment: The word "collect" means that all projects - it's part of a big project. About dependencies - is not subprojects each other, and of the project as part of a large project, and so they need to collect alternately and independent script. Need the implementation of the order described above

Comment: Collect (verb): to bring or gather together (a number of things). Is that what you mean? In that case, what should be collected? And why do they need a particular ordering?

Comment: Yes. Implementation task clean-build each project

Comment: Normally we don't need to care about order in Gradle. I'm trying to figure out what you are trying to accomplish, so I can suggest a more "gradle-ish" way to do it. Why do you need to build the projects in a certain order?

Comment: The need is only that if there is a change in any project, you need to start at clean-build the main project to rebuild all dependent projects. The main project of the WAR-project. Maybe you are right that there is no value in the order of assembly. But how to make the project recompiled with the changes?

Comment: What does collect mean? It does not matter the order of the cleaning of the projects.

Comment: Collect - is to build the project. Anybody can show implementation in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your root `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':project1'), project(':project2')
}
```

Now, when you run `gradle build` in the root project, Gradle is guaranteed to always build `project1` and `project2` first.

You can read more about multi-project builds and build order in the [User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#multiprojectFirstMessages).

Note that doing "clean" every time you build is usually a bad practice, as it only takes time without giving any benefit. Gradle automatically keeps track of which parts of a project need to be re-built, and which are not changed (and thus don't need to be re-built).

You can read more about how Gradle determines what tasks are up-to-date in [this section of the user's guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks).

> Before a task is executed for the first time, Gradle takes a snapshot of the inputs. This snapshot contains the set of input files and a hash of the contents of each file. Gradle then executes the task. If the task completes successfully, Gradle takes a snapshot of the outputs. This snapshot contains the set of output files and a hash of the contents of each file. Gradle persists both snapshots for the next time the task is executed.
>
> Each time after that, before the task is executed, Gradle takes a new snapshot of the inputs and outputs. If the new snapshots are the same as the previous snapshots, Gradle assumes that the outputs are up to date and skips the task. If they are not the same, Gradle executes the task. Gradle persists both snapshots for the next time the task is executed.